# zeromq services and data access

Tags: architecture, zeromq, soa

I'm currently experimenting with zeromq and building a distributed service oriented architecture. Each services needs to manipulate data from a common database.

What is the best way to go:

- using a shared lib across all services that defines models. Each services connects to the database
- using a data service that abstracts the database. All other services access the data through this one. Data could be transmitted using protocol buffers.

The second option seems cleaner to me but I'm afraid of the impact on performances as there is one more network communication per request to the data.

In the future, there could be data sources other than the database. That is why I had the second option in mind but I'm afraid of over engineering it.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're going the length of "doing it right", building a distributed service oriented system, with zeromq to boot, I'd say you should go the whole way and put a service in front of the database.

Regarding performance, remember Knuth's suggestion that premature optimization is the root of all evil. Better go with the cleaner option then optimize as necessary, unless you know in advance that you're going to have performance issues.
Also, abstracting the database should allow you to scale more easily (e.g. through distribution, caching etc.) should the need arise in the future.

That being said, if the other option you're considering is a shared lib, and assuming that it's also the quicker option to implement, then you could always start that way and change it later - just change the shared lib to work with a service instead of directly with the database, and all your services should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. As you said, the second option will allow to scale more easily and I effectively envision to add some caching. As I have some time ahead, I think I will try both ways and do some load testing, see what happens.

Comment: Elad, could you expand on what a service in front of the database would look like? I'm wondering specifically how it would work if you're using an ORM. Thanks!